# Android - Post Bitmap to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I'm using this solution: [How to post Bitmap to facebook using facebook sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908219/how-to-post-bitmap-to-facebook-using-facebook-sdk) to post a bitmap to Facebook but how do I modify this code to allow the user to sign in to Facebook if they are not already signed in when pressing the 'Share Photo' button? I don't want to get the user to sign in when the app launches - I only want them to sign in to Facebook when they click the Share button.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if there is no logged in person call the facebook login; else continue sharing.

See here to learn how to handle the facebook login flow using the android sdk: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook