# Using Facebook SDK 3.15. How to share a bitmap

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bitmap

I have been trying to create a solution to share a bitmap image specifically a screen shot. I have been following  this solution -> [How to post Bitmap to facebook using facebook sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908219/how-to-post-bitmap-to-facebook-using-facebook-sdk)

Therefore, this is my code,

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void shareToFacebook(Bitmap img) {

        if (img != null) {

            Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), img,  uploadPhotoRequestCallback);
            Bundle parameters = request.getParameters(); // <-- THIS IS IMPORTANT
            parameters.putString("DriveSync Telematics", "Wow look at my Score!");
            // add more params here
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
    }
```

With the callback being

```
    Request.Callback uploadPhotoRequestCallback = new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            if (response.getError() != null) {
                //post error
            } else{
                String idRploadResponse = (String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("id");
                if (idRploadResponse!= null) {

                    String fbPhotoAddress = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=" +idRploadResponse;
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Facebook upload failed");
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

And I am receiving this error

```
     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A property named "My Score" was not found on the action.  The name of the preview property must match the name of an action property.
```

Does anyone know what this means / How I can resolve my issue.

Thanks,

Peter,

Comment: Have a new related issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417668/error-when-using-facebookdialog-photosharedialogbuilder

Answer (score 0):

```
parameters.putString("DriveSync Telematics", "Wow look at my Score!");
```

^^ This line is the issue. You're essentially telling the request to set the "DriveSync Telematics" field with the value "Wow...". But there's no "DriveSync Telematics" field in the /me/photos graph API endpoint.

Here's the documentation for the user/photos graph API endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/photos/#publish

Likely what you want to do is something like:

```
parameters.putString("message", "Wow look at my Score!");
```

Comment: That got rid of the error but no facebook dialog opens for the user to post the picture. Why is this.

Comment: The method you're using doesn't pop up a dialog, it uses the graph API to post to facebook directly (if you have publish permissions). If you want to use the share dialog, you should use the FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder class https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder/

Comment: Ok but the PhotoShareDialog only allows for me to use .setPicture which only accepts links not bitmap images. How do I get around this.

Comment: There's an addPhotos (for bitmaps) or addPhotoFiles (for File objects) in the class I linked to.

Comment: @MingLi above link is broken, i cannot find reference to PhotoShareDialogBuilder anywhere.

Comment: We'll get that fixed. In the mean time, you can have a look at v3.16 of the docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.16/class/FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder/