# Error when Using FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have the following error when using the FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder, which is apart of the Facebook SDK.

```
06-25 16:06:41.120   3957-17743/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider1389xxxxxxxx
```

Her is my code below

```
private void shareToFacebook(Activity activity ,Bitmap bitmap) {


    if (bitmap != null) {
        Collection<Bitmap> screenShots = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

        screenShots.add(bitmap);

        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder(activity)
                .addPhotos(screenShots)
                .setApplicationName("DriveSync Telematics")
                .setPlace("me/photos/")
                .build();

        shareDialog.present();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap the .present() method with a canPresent().

Only certain versions of the Facebook app support the photo share dialog, and if your user is using an old version of the Facebook app, you'll get this error.