# Facebook Request not response

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

**Below is my code to share image on facebook:**

```
public static void fbShareImage(String photoPath) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);

        Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), bitmap, new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("Share", "upload success");
            }
        });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
    }
```

I want to share image on Facebook. I am using the Request function to share. But on executing request, I am not receiving any response. Any help would we valuable.

Comment: have you checked [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)?

Comment: I am not using v4.x. So this link is not suitable for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to make another request with the id of the resource in order to get the url of the image you are trying to reference in the share dialog.

So you can try the following code:

```
Callback callback = new Callback() {

   @Override     
   public void onCompleted(Response response) {

     if (response.getGraphObject() != null) {
        String imageUrl = (String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("picture");
        // call to your sharing method
    share(session, text, imageUrl);                             
      }
    }
 };


Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), imageid, null, HttpMethod.GET,     callback);
request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: not work. I add the log in onCompleted. It have not been called.

Comment: why are you not using "ShareContentLink" for sharing? Because its really hard to understand whats happening in your code, with mode details?

Comment: Or else check this link, hope it might help,  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20968646/5722385

Comment: I prefer my result that is only share image, not a link. And then "ShareContentLink" is support Facebook sdk v4.x or above. I am using v3.x